# How do I enable mathjax in bitbucket wiki?

Tags: markdown, bitbucket, wiki, mathjax

I put a private repository on Bitbucket.org, and this project needs some documentations that involve a lot of math stuff. I want to use Bitbucket Wiki and edit it in Markdown but how should I also enable MathJax to allow me to type in math equations in the markdown file?

The official documentation of bitbucket (https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+a+wiki) does not seem to mention it. And I searched Google but found few useful results. Any idea?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 7):

As of January 2014, Bitbucket only [supports MathJax in for restructuredText files](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/5420/enable-mathjax-for-restructuredtext-files).

There is an open [feature request for MathJax in markdown files](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/7908/enable-mathjax-in-markdown).

Comment: Seems to still be the case

Answer (score 6):

I also searched & searched a few hours and I could not find it. But you need to use the [reStructuredText :math: interpreted text role](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/roles.html#math). One example is given below:

```
:math:`E[(Y - g(X))^{2} | X = x]`
```

You can also set math as default and leave out :math: in the above markup.

```
.. default-role:: math
```